# Zwave WITHOUT home assistant?

Tags: zwave

I am replacing some of my Sonoff Basic hacks with UL approved Z-Wave wall switches.  Node Red is my primary IOT brains and I will be adding the OpenZWave node to my toolbox.  I plan to use the Aeotek Z-Stick on the Raspberry Pi 3 that is also my MQTT broker.

However, every tutorial or discussion of using the Z-Stick on the Pi also assumes Home Assistant.  I tried HA, twice, and still don't like it.  I find it too complex for my purposes and I don't want to learn yet another scripting language.  I like Node Red.

Has anyone integrated the Z-Stick into their IOT/Node Red *without* also installing Home Assistant?